# ExtJS - Combobox with store add a custom selection

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way to add without changing an EXT store (myStore.carTypes in this example) an option which just says "None"? with a custom value of ""

```
type: 'combo',
fieldLabel: 'Car',
name: 'carName',
otrId: 'carName',
hidden: false,
allowBlank: true,
store: 'myStore.carTypes',
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'name',
maskRe: /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are my assumptions based on reading your question:
You don't want an entry("None") in the store but you still want that entry in the combobox.
You want an entry called None with value "" but having problems as your displayField and valueField is same.

I have a trick to solve this problems. First create a new store at combobox with an entry "None" and have a listener which changes the store data beforequery. Make sure that combobox valueField and displayField are different (abbr, name) in this example. In the beforequery listener we modify the store which is associated with the combobox and copy data from the other store (states1) in this example. while copying we copy the name from states1 store as name and abbr both in our new store. This should solve your problem Please look at the code below or see it in action at this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jmt). If you are running the fiddle please make sure the theme selected is a classic one.

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function () {
    var states1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
        data: [{
            "abbr": "Alabama",
            "name": "Alabama"
        }, {
            "abbr": "Alaska",
            "name": "Alaska"
        }, {
            "abbr": "Arizona",
            "name": "Arizona"
        }]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            data: [{
                name: 'None',
                abbr: ''
            }, ]
        }),
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr',
        editable: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            beforequery: function (queryEvent, opts) {
                states1.each(function (record) { //replace states1 with your store var
                    queryEvent.combo.store.add({
                        name: record.data.name,
                        abbr: record.data.name
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if this helped you so it can help people in the future. Or comment what's wrong with my answer.